# What scope is required to access the list of AzureAD groups via MS Graph API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add a feature to a MS Graph API app written in Node.JS. The app was built from a [Microsoft template](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-nodeexpressapp/tree/master/demo). The app needs to fetch a list of Azure AD groups whose names begin with a prefix. I am having trouble getting it to work.

I copied this working code:

```
const client = graph.Client.init({...});
const events = await client
  .api('/me/events')
  .select('subject,organizer,start,end')
  .orderby('createdDateTime DESC')
  .get();
```

...and changed the api query according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) I found. I have commented out the filter just to try to get the basic query to work.

```
const client = graph.Client.init({...});
const events = await client
  .api('/groups')
  .select('id,displayName')
  // .filter("startsWith(displayName,'Prefix')")
  .get();
```

But the query returns this error:

```
GraphError {
  statusCode: 403,
  code: 'Authorization_RequestDenied',
  message: 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.',
  requestId: 'f5330dbd-c7a9-4126-a227-10a656a11083',
  date: 2020-07-10T22:25:24.000Z,
  body: '{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied"...}'
}
```

I'm not 100% certain the URI is correct. I would expect a 404 if the URI was wrong, but that may be expecting too much. Perhaps this `/group` API does not correlate to Azure AD groups.

OTOH, do I need to add a new scope to request access to the group information? The current scope list used by the application looks like this:

```
OAUTH_SCOPES='profile offline_access user.read calendars.read'
```

I have not found a reference for graph queries and scopes for Azure AD. I tried adding 'groups.read' to the list of scopes, but that did not work.

I would appreciate not only an answer, but link to documentation as well. I have to add a few other features from Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least to most privileged Permission for querying Groups is `Group.Read.All` as per your linked document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions